# NHibernate + SQLite, excessive loading time of object graph

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, nhibernate

At program startup I'm loading a complete object graph of the entire database, no lazy-loading, into a domain object. I understand this is not the typical usage, but that's outside the question.  The database is only accessed by a single user/program. And the following condition is about this single start-up load operation;

As the database grows, the loading time is becoming substantial. I have these numbers for two states of the same database;

```
1. Size 1.6MB, 3 main tables row count; 1100, 2400, 13400. Load time;    44s
2. Size 3.6MB, 3 main tables row count; 2800, 6200, 26700. Load time; 3m 40s
```

The 3 tables have these columns;

```
7x integer, 4x numeric, 6x text, 2x datetime  (2800 rows)
7x integer, 3x numeric, 11x text, 2x datetime (6200 rows)
4x integer, 2x numeric, 5x text, 1x datetime  (26700 rows)
```

All mappings are `1:m`.

CPU Profiler shows this; http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/4444/6rh.png

Would appreciate advice on;

1. What load time could (very roughly) be expected/targeted for this condition? Are these times reasonable or totally off the chart?
2. what may be the bottlenecks?
3. may a different database perform better? (which?)
4. any relevant suggestion to improve load time

---

EDIT:

Mappings;

```
   public class AccountBaseMap : ClassMap<AccountBase>
    {
       public AccountBaseMap()
           : base()
       {
           Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();      
           HasMany(x => x.Executions).KeyColumn("Account__Id").Cascade.All();
           HasMany(x => x.Orders).KeyColumn("Account__Id").Cascade.All();
           //...value types omitted                 
           References(x => x.RiskProfile).Cascade.All();                
       }
   }

   public class LocalOrderMap : ClassMap<LocalOrder>
    {
       public LocalOrderMap()
            : base()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Account__Id);    
            //...value types omitted       
            HasMany(x => x.StatusDetails).KeyColumn("Order__id").Cascade.All(); 
        }
  }

    public class OrderStatusDetailMap : ClassMap<OrderStatusDetail>
    {
       public OrderStatusDetailMap()
            : base()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            //...value types omitted         
            Map(x => x.Order__Id); 
            Map(x => x.Time).CustomType("timestamp");                 
        }
     }
```

NHibernate ShowSql, from query;

> _session.CreateCriteria(T)().List(T)();

Output; (Was about 1000 lines, similar removed at .....)

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=ie7mn

---

EDIT 2:

NHibernate config;

```
 var fcfg = Fluently.Configure()
     .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connString)); 

 fcfg.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TMap1>().Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()));

if (typeof(TMap1) != typeof(TMap2))
    fcfg.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TMap2>().Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()));

fcfg.ExposeConfiguration(c => cfg = c).Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache());

sessionFactory = fcfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I don't use any logging framework, so think no logging should be on. Though I do currently run Debug builds, shall make a check if Release build makes any difference.

About architecture; Solution is set to Any CPU, project builds to x86 (platform target). I run both on x86 XP and x64 Windows 7, and load correct System.Data.SQLite.dll based on that.

Btw, I'm using `NHibernate 3.1.0.4`

Comment: Post your mappings here. Define prefetchpaths for the objectgraph or use Futures to better batch the reads. Use ShowSql in the configuration or NH-logging to look at the sql generated.

Comment: @Firo Please see edit above. I'm not familiar with using prefetchpaths or Futures, but will look into this if you mean it should make a great difference(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out that I only had to change one single thing;

In my class maps, added to all 1:M collections `Fetch.Subselect()`

> HasMany(x => x.Orders).**Fetch.Subselect()**.KeyColumn("Account__Id").Not.LazyLoad().Cascade.All().Inverse();

*(I also added `Not.LazyLoad()` there, but that made no difference so can be omitted)*

With this change I can keep my fluent configuration convention `DefaultLazy.Never`, which is good as I don't need to make properties and methods virtual. And I can keep unidirectional relationship. Basically, no changes or special tweaks to my previous code beyond this detail.

Load time for current database, now 4.8mb went from 11minutes down to 13sec.

Answer (score 0):

## Few suggestions / Questions

- Try turning off all logging.
- Using the correct x86/x64 arch for SQLite?
- What does the NH Config look like?
- Ensure you're using the correct SQLite NH driver.
- Do you have the **default_schema** property set?
- Are you creating a **SessionFactory** for every request?

And if all else fails:

- Try SQL CE 4

Logging everything in NHibernate, (especially 3.x or later) can cause a *significant* performance problems when debugging.

Comment: Answered some of your points in edit. What is the purpose of default_schema? By SQLite NH driver, you mean that specified in the configuration (SQLiteConfiguration.Standard) ?   I'm only using one SessionFactory, and this single operation of discussion is just one request of a single session.

Answer (score 0):

since you have a backreference on the other side set inverse

```
// in Accountmap
HasMany(x => x.Executions).KeyColumn("Account__Id").Cascade.All().Inverse();
HasMany(x => x.Orders).KeyColumn("Account__Id").Cascade.All().Inverse();

// in Accountmap
HasMany(x => x.StatusDetails).KeyColumn("Order__id").Cascade.All().Inverse();
```

backreferences should be references instead of properties

```
Map(x => x.Account__Id); -> References(x => x.Account);
Map(x => x.Order__Id);   -> References(x => x.Order);
```

while querying batch the queries with futures to get the data in one roundtrip

```
// ignore the results, the query only loads the data into session cache
session.QueryOver<Order>()
    .Fetch(x => x.StatusDetails).Eager
    .Future();

var accounts = session.QueryOver<AccountBase>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Orders).Eager
    .Future();


return accounts.ToList();    // both queries execute here
```

check your equals and gethashcode implementation to take the id into account just to prevent bugs in corener cases

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as AccountBase;
    return other != null && IsTransient ? ReferenceEquals(this, other) : Id == other.Id;
}

private bool IsTransient { get { return Id == 0; } }

private int? _cachedHashcode;
public override int GetHashcode()
{
    if (!_cachedHashcode.HasValue)
        _cachedHashcode = IsTransient ? base.GetHashCode() : Id.GetHashCode();
    return _cachedHashcode.Value;
}
```

also some minor tweaks:

- use the fluent api and remove unnessesary anon delegates
- delay Defaultlazy.Never() to the actual use case

  ```
  var fcfg = Fluently.Configure()
      .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connString))
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TMap1>())
      .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache());

  if (typeof(TMap1) != typeof(TMap2))
      fcfg.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TMap2>()));

  cfg = fcfg.BuildConfiguration();
  sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  `var accounts =..`, is a set of orders..? I see these `Eager.Future` quickly loads into cache, but can't see how I should load the root entity, `List<AccountBase>`, while taking advantage of that cache?  I'll look into the reference-backreferences, but the futures should work regardless, or?  I made them actually only to force-update an entity without saving it by it's parent.

Comment: `accounts` is your `List<AccountBase>`. Filling the sessioncache is needed so the `AccountBase.Orders.StatusDetails` are all initialized. You can use it as is.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. What I get from that query is a list of 953 accounts, obviously duplicates as there are only 4 accounts. 953 is the number of orders, so one account for each order. Do you think this is due to my use of property-backreferences, so I'm forced to change that?

Comment: this occures normally when your equals/gethashcode implementation is not correct or you eager fetch more than one lvl

Comment: Well, I finally found a solution. Your info was helpful to get me there, though in the end, none of it was required (see my answer). But thanks! :)

Comment: It was me, technically your answer gave a lot of unnecessary work, and missed the target. I fully appreciate the effort of course, but in terms of working solution it seems off. Maybe it's inappropriate vote..?

Comment: Most of the time it's better to use futures instead of subselect because Roundtrips are more expensive than joins on primary keys. Also i already answered questions where mapping of ForeignKey (e.g. `Account__Id`) instead of a Reference generated Exceptions. Maybe in your special use case the subselect is fine and you only do 1 load and never update so no Exceptions, there may be others having these problems.

Comment: I see. My philosophy is not to introduce extra references or complexity in my domain just for the sake of the DAL. I have a lot of multithread events going on so trying to keep things as decoupled as possible. So far Fetch.Subselect is the only way I've been able to load a 3-level deep unidirectional graph without the cartesian-issue. It just seems very hard with NH for something I expect to be easily achievable.. As for updates I only work with transient instances, and set ParentIds manually before save, but so far it's clockwork, so think it's ok for my case.

Comment: NH tries hard to be persistence igorant. Especially References instead of ids are more object oriented. NH has `order.Account = Session.Load<Account>(accountId);` which does the same thing as setting id but leaves the Order in the right state, you can access Account later if needed.

Comment: "It just seems very hard with NH for something I expect to be easily achievable" -> loading a complete object graph efficiently from a sql database is no easy task. It depends on use case, database capabilities, present indices, number of records and so on. There is no silver bullet and the level of tuning options in NH are better than most other ORMs. Try to search "eager loading an object graph effiently" with other ORMs and you'll see

Comment: I understand back-reference has it's purpose. I just don't get why some seem to mean it should always be used, even when it may have no use in the domain model. I think I dragged the FKs into my domain to avoid some transient/StaleState exception issues. For my use a failed insert/update is the worst ever scenario. So basically I make it hard to occur by taking responsibility of the FKs myself. So I may break a principle to achieve a rock stable performance.

Comment: "no easy task"; What I meant is it should be easy to specify in terms of syntax/query, as an ORM feature. If it's hard to implement is another thing. Though EF does it very easily, in my simple tests, but is unacceptable for other reasons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36765/discussion-between-firo-and-bretddog)